# Do subroutine signatures work with overload.pm?

Tags: perl, overloading, signature

With the flowing code..

```
use experimental 'signatures';

package O {
    use overload
        q[""]  => \&as_str
    ;
    sub as_str ($self) { "Hello World!" }
    sub new ($class) {
        bless {}, $class
    }
};

my $o = O->new;
print "$o";
```

I'll get,

> Too many arguments for subroutine 'O::as_str'

How can I use both (a) signatures and (b) overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs on [`overload.pm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/overload#Calling-Conventions-and-Magic-Autogeneration)

> Three arguments are passed to all subroutines specified in the use overload directive (with exceptions - see below, particularly "nomethod").
>
> 1. The first of these is the operand providing the overloaded operator implementation - in this case, the object whose minus() method is being called.
> 2. The second argument is the other operand, or undef in the case of a unary operator.
> 3. The third argument is set to TRUE if (and only if) the two operands have been swapped. Perl may do this to ensure that the first argument ($self) is an object implementing the overloaded operation, in line with general object calling conventions.

Basically, `overload` supports binary operators and all of the subs it calls are prototyped to accept three arguments. So with this in mind, you'll want

```
sub as_str ($lhs, $rhs, $is_swapped) { "Hello World!" }
```

Or you can tell it to [ignore the other arguments using the `$`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures)

```
sub as_str ($lhs, $, $) { "Hello World!" }
```